# PDF Presentation on TV using Raspbmc and UPnP

Tags: raspbmc

I make a lot of slide presentations in the PDF format. I currently have a raspberry pi running raspbmc as a HTPC. Is it possible to stream a PDF slide presentation from my laptop running Xubuntu 13.10 to the TV through the raspberry pi?

Comment: Not sure about RaspBMC but on the bare Linux one you can use FBI with GhostScript to play PDF files form the console to a connected HDMI monitor. Furthermore you can control it via the command line. So you can easily make a interface for any Smarphone via a AJAX and Node.js or Perl or simple EXEC bash.